# how to mock multiple fetch calls being made in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function, as below, that performs 2 fetch calls within the same function

```
getNames() {
    var qs = require("qs");
    fetch(<URL>,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: qs.stringify({
          firstName: this.state.firstName,
          lastName: this.state.lastName
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
      });

    var url = new URL(<someURL>)

    fetch(<someURL>).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
     ...do something...
      }
     })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("no response");

        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I am testing this using Jest and Enzyme on React. The above belongs to the GetName component. Below is my test case:

```
describe('getName', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<GetName />).instance();

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.fetch.resetMocks();
    });

    it('positive flow', () => {
        global.fetch.mockResolvedValue(
            new Response(JSON.stringify({data: "mockData"}))
        );
        const state = {
            firstName: "don",
            lastName: "Lee"
        };
        wrapper.setState(state);
        const actualValue = wrapper.getNames();
        expect(actualValue).toBeUndefined();
    });
 });
```

Once I do this, I get an error that `TypeError: body used already for: undefined`

I understand that the fetch here is being used for the POST call, but how do I make sure that I can mock both the fetch calls within the function?

I have also tried `fetch.mockResponse` and `fetch.mockResponses` and also `fetch.mockResponseOnce`. None of them seem to help me mock them more than once and I get this error with all functions mentioned.

Is there any other way to mock both the fetch calls?

Comment: what I did was split the function with two fetch into two separate methods, that way I could mock them separately.